# Side effects having an html page with just an img tag?

Tags: html

If I just have an `<img>` as an html page, could there be any security risks? In other words, no `<html><head>or<body>` tags.

So let's say it is my `default.htm` page.

Comment: What security features do you think those tags provide, which you would be concerned about losing? I'm not aware that they do anything of that nature, is there something in the HTML spec you can point to which I have missed? I can't really see what you are worrying about. It's not good practice to make a HTML document without these tags, but it is technically permitted, and most browsers/rendering engines will work around it.

Comment: What security are you afraid of with your image ?

Comment: The browser is still going to be smart enough to render the content.  Though it's certainly strange to do this in the first place, and is *probably* an indication of a design flaw somewhere else.  Not sure what *security risks* you're thinking of...

Comment: How does the lack of `<html><head><body>` allow someone to hack you?

Comment: I don't know, just wanted to get some opinions in case I'm missing something. Just curious.

Comment: Your rep suggests you've been around long enough to know this site prefers facts to opinions (in fact, opinion-based questions are specifically off-topic), and your question / concern seems to have no basis other than personal speculation, it's not even clear what aspects of security particularly you are thinking of. The short answer is "no, these are just HTML rendering tags and do not impact security in any way".

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. I knew it might have been a dumb question. Still wanted to get the opinions. Sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: @ADyson: If the page truly does consist of nothing but a single img, then all six opening and closing tags for html, head and body will add up to a sizable portion of the page size. Might as well leave them out entirely since they're not actually needed (the fact that leaving them out is technically permitted means browsers don't even need to work around it).

Comment: @BoltClock I guess, although pages usually end up growing eventually. And you'd have to be on a pretty slow connection for those few bytes to make a difference to the loading time or anything.

Comment: @ADyson: Also true. Big percentages, small absolute numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The html, head and body elements are always going to be there. You can't actually have an HTML page without them, even if you leave out the tags.

The following two valid HTML documents are equivalent (whitespace notwithstanding):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Image</title>
<img src="lightbulb.jpg" alt="">
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Image</title></head>
  <body><img src="lightbulb.jpg" alt=""></body>
</html>
```

So even if there were any such security risks associated with leaving those elements out (which there aren't), the fact that they will always be there renders that concern moot.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the insight.